# comparacion de un caracter de una cadena del tipo puntero

Tags: c++

TEngo este código y el problema es que no me estaría funcionando. Lo que necesito es saber si el primer caracter de esa cadena es un punto.

```
  DIR* pDirectory = opendir(pcPath);
  struct dirent* pDirent;
  
   while (pDirent = readdir(pDirectory)) {
         if (&pDirent->d_name[0] != ".") {
            // pero nunca pasa por aca aunquue el archvo tenga el nombre
            // .archivo.txt
            ...
```

Comment: pon `'.'` en vez de `"."`

Comment: Genial! Funcionó perfecto

Comment: Las comillas dobles delimitan strings, pero tú querías comparar caracteres, que se delimitan con comillas simples (además de que los strings no se pueden comparar con `==` ni `!=`, sino que deben usarse funciones como `strcmp()`)